# Logcat doesn't show some logs

Tags: android, logcat

Look at the following code:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] tokens = line.split("\t");

Log.d("line", line);
Log.d("tokens size", String.valueOf(tokens.length));
Log.d("token", tokens[0]);
```

When run it just prints this:

D/tokens size: 1

Dark assembly magic or something?

Comment: Maybe you're filtering logs for `tokens size`?

Comment: Could be dark assembly magic. Have you triple checked you're not accidentally filtering in your logcat search box?

Comment: I am not filtering yea, just didn't post the rest of the irrelevant logs.